# Flex: Putting multiple lists in a scroller

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flex-spark

I want to put multiple lists in a scroller (where each list is not scrollable). What I am doing below works, but there is a huge random gap after each list. I've checked renderers.Pending and there is nothing causing the gap. I notice it only happens when I set verticalScrollPolicy to off. I do not want to set it to on or else the list itself will be scrollable.

```
<s:Scroller height="80%" width="100%">
            <s:VGroup width="100%">
                <s:Label bottom="5" width="100%" styleName="normalWhite" text="Heading 1" textAlign="left" fontSize="18" />
                <s:List id="pendingList1"
                        width="100%" 
                        includeIn="pending"
                        dataProvider="{Info}" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
                        itemRenderer="renderers.Pending"
                        styleName="customList" alternatingItemColors="[#13237d]" 
                        selectionColor="#009de0"
                        dragEnabled="false"
                        dragMoveEnabled="false"
                        dropEnabled="false"
                        verticalScrollPolicy="off">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify" gap="1"/>
                    </s:layout>
                </s:List>

                <s:Label bottom="5" width="100%" styleName="normalWhite" text="Heading 2" textAlign="left" fontSize="18" />
                <s:List id="pendingList2"
                        width="100%" 
                        includeIn="pending"
                        dataProvider="{Info}" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
                        itemRenderer="renderers.Pending"
                        styleName="customList" alternatingItemColors="[#13237d]" 
                        selectionColor="#009de0"
                        dragEnabled="false"
                        dragMoveEnabled="false"
                        dropEnabled="false"
                        verticalScrollPolicy="off">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify" gap="1"/>
                    </s:layout>
                </s:List>
           </s:VGroup>
 </s:Scroller>
```

Comment: Try by setting the `height` as `100%` for all the `List`.

Comment: That just cuts off the items in each list.

Comment: I didn't set it to 100% so that all of the items would be displayed without scroll for each list. Then the scroller is supposed to allow the user to scroll through all of the lists and their items.

Comment: My first impulse was going to be to recommend that you append the two dataProviders and use a rendererFunction to control the display; but each list uses the same rendererFunction and dataProvider.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Both lists are pulling from the same data, the only difference is that each list handles a different category.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tried to simulate your problem but i didn't get it. My code is working fine as you said.

**test.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var Info:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]);  

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Info.addAll(new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]));
                Info.addAll(new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]));
                Info.addAll(new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]));
                Info.addAll(new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]));
                Info.addAll(new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]));
                Info.addAll(new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]));
                Info.addAll(new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]));
                Info.addAll(new ArrayCollection(["num 1","num 2","num 3","num 4","num 5","num 6","num 7","num 8","num 9","num 10"]));

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Scroller height="80%" width="100%">
        <s:VGroup width="100%">
            <s:Label bottom="5" width="100%" styleName="normalWhite" text="Heading 1" textAlign="left" fontSize="18" />
            <s:List id="pendingList1"
                    width="100%" 

                    dataProvider="{Info}" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
                    itemRenderer="renderers.Pending"
                    styleName="customList" alternatingItemColors="[#13237d]" 
                    selectionColor="#009de0"
                    dragEnabled="false"
                    dragMoveEnabled="false"
                    dropEnabled="false"
                    >
                <s:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify" gap="1"/>
                </s:layout>
            </s:List>

            <s:Label bottom="5" width="100%" styleName="normalWhite" text="Heading 2" textAlign="left" fontSize="18" />
            <s:List id="pendingList2"
                    width="100%" 

                    dataProvider="{Info}" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"

                    styleName="customList" alternatingItemColors="[#13237d]" 
                    selectionColor="#009de0"
                    dragEnabled="false"
                    dragMoveEnabled="false"
                    dropEnabled="false"
                    >
                <s:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify" gap="1"/>
                </s:layout>
            </s:List>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Application>
```

**renderers.Pending**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">

    <s:Label text="{data}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Please don't look for coding standard. its too bad here.
I am using Flash Builder 4 & sdk version is 4.1

Comment: I'm using Flash Builder 4.7, with Flex 4.6, and AIR SDK 3.4. I am experiencing this bug/error in the iOS simulator.

Comment: I think you are using `IconItemRenderer` as `renderers.Pending`. Try `ItemRenderer` instead. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, I'm using the ItemRenderer tag.

Comment: I'm noticing it has to do with renderers.Pending. I put everything into a VGroup.

Comment: It has to do with list items of different heights.

Answer (score 0):

Setting variableRowHeight="false" worked and got rid of the random white space. However, now the height of all the list items is the height of the tallest one. It's temporary solution I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Gap on the VGroup to 0